# mysql user batch issue

Tags: mysql, sql, windows, batch-file

My goal is to get a simple batch file to run automatically on a Windows 7 Professional SP1 server with MariaDB 5.5.

The FILE is SQL_e.bat :

```
pause
mysql -u user-ppassword -D DBname -e "source C:\tmp\test.sql"
pause
```

The test.sql is a simple create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `DateTime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `Part` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`DateTime`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

opening cmd.exe with promt C:\Users\user and entering:

```
mysql -u user-ppassword -D DBname -e "source C:\tmp\test.sql"
```

WORKS

executing the SQL_e.bat gives the message

> 'mysql' not recognized command.

If I add the path in SQL_e.bat with

```
cd C:\Program Files\MariaDB 5.5\bin
```

I get

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' <10061>

The C:\tmp\test.sq is local on the server.
The user has HOST % and Allow access to ALL Global privileges.

Comment: Did you show the complete `SQL_e.bat`? Or does it contains something like `set path=c:\tmp` before?

Comment: There is no set path in the SQL_e.bat file. Should there be? The user to connect to the server is not the same MySQl user if that is an issue.

Comment: I added "set path=c:\tmp" with no difference. It works under the cmd prompt but not as a batch. The issue seems to be either the user privileges or MySQL configuration?

Comment: You shouldn't set `path`, but probably it's not containing the directory for your mysql binary

Comment: I have no set path used. I added the cmd echo %userdomain%\%username%. Both the cmd and batch show the same domain & user. There is almost nothing changed in any MySQL ini or cnf file. I am at a loss what to look at to find the discrepancy?